# C++ university course

Tags: c++

Do you know any university which has its C++ course available online? I'm looking for something similar to MIT-style online lectures (lecture notes, projects and examples, assignments, exams, solutions and video content).

[This](http://ocw.mit.edu/OcwWeb/Electrical-Engineering-and-Computer-Science/6-096January--IAP--2009/CourseHome/index.htm) is what I've found on MIT, but id doesn't have video content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about C++ specifically, but in terms of video lectures on programming concepts, check out this:

http://academicearth.org/subjects/computer-science

Answer (score 2):

use iTunes U search for the course in the stanford 
they have a course on itunes for c++

Answer (score 2):

The Stanford Programming Abstractions course (CS106B) is available as "open courseware" including rather low resolution videos. It is meant as a second programming course after their introductory programming course and is taught in C++:

[Programming Abstractions in C++](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs106b/cs106b.1152/index.shtml)

It is sort of an introduction to C++ programming course and a data structures and algorithms course rolled into one. Their introductory programming course which generally precedes this one is taught in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Most universities will be quite protective of such things. I suspect the best thing to do would be to A) find a project you want to work on and B) buy a very good book.

Comment: MIT does this already for a lot of his course : http://ocw.mit.edu/OcwWeb/web/courses/courses/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

Check out: https://www.coursera.org/

It is relatively new and there are plenty of universities with several courses.